# call service rest on click with Backbone

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I want to call a rest service (post) when I press on the button login but it doesn't launch any service it just add a "?" at the end of the url of my application.

here is my js :

```
(function ($) {
var authentication = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
            Username: "",
            Password: ""
        },
        url:'../../rest/login'
});



var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new authentication(),
    el: $("#login-form"),
    events: {
        "click button#login": "login"
    },

    login: function(){
        alert("ici");
        this.model.save({username: this.$el.find("#inUser")}, {
        password: this.$el.find("#inPswd")}, {
            success: function() {
                /* update the view now */
            },
            error: function() {
                /* handle the error code here */
            }
        });
    }   

})
})
(jQuery);
```

And here is my form :

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="inUser"></input>
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="inPswd"></input>
<button id="login">Login</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `.save()` method call because you send `username` and `password` in two different objects.

Also to stop adding question mark `?` sign (stop submitting your form) you need to add `event.preventDefault();` and/or `return false;` to your button click handler.

Here is a fix:

```
login: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("ici");
    this.model.save({
            username: this.$el.find("#inUser"),
            password: this.$el.find("#inPswd")
        }, {
            success: function() {
                /* update the view now */
            },
            error: function() {
                /* handle the error code here */
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```